# run jar file without swing libraries

Tags: java

I have program , I create the jar file, but then when I run the jar file nothing is display,
is it because it is not an swing program? How should I run this program?

```
`package first;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] arguments) {
.........
```

`

Answer (score 0):

assuming folder structure & from code I don't see you need any external jar

```
c > temp >first > Main.java
```

compile

```
c:\temp\first>javac  Main.java
```

execute

```
c:\temp>java first.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your jar file is yourJarFile.jar, you run it like this: `java -jar yourJarFile.jar`

Comment: that solve my problem, but why click on jar file doesn't start the program?

Comment: Right click you jar, go to properties and add your java executable to the "Opens With" textField.